# Fragment being created again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragment to implement viewpager,the viewpager is also a fragment,I am implementing a back button and clicking on it the fragment goes back to the previous fragment, on pressing back button the previous fragment is again loading and getting the response again. How can I prevent that. I have added my code below.

Photo Fragment:-

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {           

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_photo, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    if (sharedPref.contains("isViewPagerStarted")) {
    isViewPagerStarted = sharedPref.getBoolean("isViewPagerStarted",false);
    }

    Log.e("pagerstart", "" + isViewPagerStarted);
    if (isViewPagerStarted) {
        backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation RightSwipe = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                R.anim.slide_out_left);
        backButton.startAnimation(RightSwipe);

        backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.plc_gallery).cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = getActivity();
    FontHelper.setFontFace(galleryHeader, FontType.FONT5);

    getGalleryInfo();
    onClickGridView();

}

private void onClickGridView() {
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

            callViewPagerStarted();

            ViewPagerFragment viewPagerFragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putInt("position", position);
            bun.putStringArray("fullImage", imageUrls);
            // bun.putStringArray("desc", description);
            viewPagerFragment.setArguments(bun);
            transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragment,
                    viewPagerFragment, "viewFrag");

            transaction.commit();

            /*
             * // Send intent to SingleViewActivity Intent intent = new
             * Intent(getActivity(),ViewPagerActivity.class); // Pass image
             * index Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
             * bundle.putInt("position",position);
             * bundle.putStringArray("imageArray",imageUrls);
             * bundle.putStringArray("description",description);
             * intent.putExtras(bundle); startActivity(intent);
             */
        }

    });

}

public void callViewPagerStarted() {

    editor.putBoolean("isViewPagerStarted", true);
    editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    /* getGalleryInfo(); */
}

private void getGalleryInfo() {
    GetMesaGallery getTempleInfo = new GetMesaGallery();
    // getTempleInfo.setAppID("8eb24199-6838-43ac-b9ca-40031ab37e65");
    ProgresBar.start(mContext);

    ServiceManager.instance().enqueue(getTempleInfo, new ServiceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Response arg0) {

            ProgresBar.stop();
            GetMesaGallerysResponse response = (GetMesaGallerysResponse) arg0;
            if (response.isValid()) {
                response.getImageDto();
                final ArrayList<ImageDto> galleryImageList = response
                        .getImageDto();
                thumbnailUrls = new String[galleryImageList.size()];
                // description = new String[galleryImageList.size()];
                imageUrls = new String[galleryImageList.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < galleryImageList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        thumbnailUrls[i] = galleryImageList.get(i)
                                .getthumbnailURL();

                        /*
                         * description[i] = galleryImageList.get(i)
                         * .getdescription();
                         */
                        imageUrls[i] = galleryImageList.get(i).getimageURL();
                        loadGridView();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {

            }

        }
    });

}

private void loadGridView() {

    try {

        GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                thumbnailUrls);

        // Set the adapter to the gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Add variable to outState here
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

ViewPager Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewpager, container,
                false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);

    backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation RightSwipe = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
            R.anim.slide_in_right);
    backButton.startAnimation(RightSwipe);

    Log.e("insdie", "viewpager");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    position = arguments.getInt("position");
    Log.e("position", "" + position);
    fullImageUris = arguments.getStringArray("fullImage");
    txtDesc = arguments.getStringArray("desc");

    FontHelper.setFontFace(description, FontType.FONT6);
    description.setPaintFlags(description.getPaintFlags()
            | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    /*
     * List<Fragment> imageFragments = getFragments();
     */
    pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager(), fullImageUris);

    mPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    mIndicator.setViewPager_Text(mPager,description,txtDesc);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

/*
 * @Override public void onResume() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 * super.onResume(); pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity()
 * .getSupportFragmentManager(),fullImageUri);
 * mPager.setCurrentItem(position); mPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
 * mIndicator.setViewPager_Text(mPager, description, txtDesc); }
 */
@OnClick(R.id.left_arrow)
public void tapLeftArrow() {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return mPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

@OnClick(R.id.right_arrow)
public void tapRightArrow() {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);

}

@OnClick(R.id.imgBackBtn)
public void moveToPreviousFragment() {

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();

    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");

    }
    // getActivity().onBackPressed();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply checked the instance of my fragment and solved the problem

```
public static PhotoFragment instance() {
        if (photoFragment == null) {
            photoFragment = new PhotoFragment();
        }
        return photoFragment;
    }
```